# VBA, Storing Value in Cell with Format

Tags: excel, vba

I am opening a workbook, storing a cell as a variable, closing the workbook, then using this variable to populate the body of my email.

Is it possible to copy the format of the copied cell with it?

Cell I am copying:

[image]

How it shows in my email:

[image]

I would like to show it how it is in the first photo

**Code:**

```
Workbooks.Open (Sheets("Input").Range("B3") & Sheets("Input").Range("B6"))
cibcomm = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Global Summary").Range("K59").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False


With objEmail
    .to = ""
    .cc = ""
    .Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("B8")
    .HTMLBody = "Hi User, <br><br>" _
                & "Can you please see below. <br><br>" _
                & cibcomm & "<br><br><br>" _
                & "Thanks, <br><br>" _
                & "Louis"
    .Attachments.Add (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("B3") & Sheets("Input").Range("B9"))
    .Display
    
End With
```

Comment: [`Rangetohtml`](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) may be helpful.

Comment: Yes it would but all my copied data is in one cell, I think any format from `Rangetohtml` may be applied to the one cell. ie I cant really separate lines I think as I am using one variable for the full cell K59

Comment: When you differentially format characters in an Excel worksheet cell, the format applied is a property of the `.Characters` property of the cell. So, as a minimum, you are going to have to examine the Excel worksheet cell *character by character*.

Comment: Use Word. You can copy directly from Word in to an HTMLBody. You can also put tabular data in to a Word doc. If you need variables to change in the text then the solution you are looking for is called `MailMerge`: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3